# Unable to import sbt project into intellij using custom sbt-launch.jar

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I need features in sbt more recent than the built-in Intellij . So I am using a `Custom sbt launch-jar` pointing to my 0.13.9 sbt.  The custom sbt *is* getting invoked and gets further along in the build than the built-in Intellij.

However the build fails: and it seems it were looking for built-in intellij classes:

```
2016-02-13 12:54:27,355 [ 171733]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - 
   Error while importing SBT project:

    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
     <snip>
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.ReadProject$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

See complete log in /Users/steve/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea14/sbt.last.log
```

So then we seem to have a Catch-22: Intellij does allow using a Custom sbt. But then it needs classes from its own built-in sbt??

Anyone have experience with the custom sbt build and know how to resolve this?

I am on IJ 14.1.4.

Comment: No, that's the sbt extractor plugin for intellij. Haven't tried a custom sbt launch jar, but it should work if all the major versions match

Comment: In IntelliJ 2016.1 it is still almost impossible to import/open a sbt based project.  Out of my last 10 attempts it only worked once.